# How to replace backslashes in a regex saved as string, and to get it to work?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array of names, which I use this regex [`/^\[.*?[ЁёА-я].*?\]/g`](https://regex101.com/r/skDDte/2) filter to get those that only have Cyrillic letters in square brackets that occur at the start of the name *(ex. reg1...test1 below)* which works fine, I then save this regex to a database *(sqlite3)* as text. Now when I get it back from the table it is a string, which I need to replace `\` with `\\` for the regex to work again.

I tried

- `.replace(/\\/g, '\\\\');`
- `.replace(/(?<!\\)\\(?!\\)/g, '\\\\');`
- `.replaceAll("\\", "\\\\");`

but as can be seen in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sx78e5u4/2/) these don't work as intended.

```js
let arr = [
    '[Лорем ипсум долор] - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
    '[Уллум велит ностер еи] sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua (X22)',    
    '[Пауло темпор те меа] Duis aute irure dolor (20X)',
    'Duis aute irure dolor (20X) [Пауло темпор те меа]',
    '[Lorem ipsum] sunt in culpa qui officia [Test]'
];

// Ok - this is before saving into the DB
let reg1 = /^\[.*?[ЁёА-я].*?\]/g;
let test1 = arr.filter(x => x.match(reg1));

// Ok - but I'd prefer not to save the regex in this form 
let reg2 = "^\\[.*?[ЁёА-я].*?\\]";
reg2 = new RegExp(reg2,'g');
let test2 = arr.filter(x => x.match(reg2));

// Ok - but no idea how to insert the regex part after the String.raw as 
// String.raw`${reg3}` doesn't work and String.raw(`${reg3}`) gives an error
let reg3 = String.raw`^\[.*?[ЁёА-я].*?\]`;
reg3 = new RegExp(reg3,'g');
let test3 = arr.filter(x => x.match(reg3));

// These don't work.
let reg4 = '^\[.*?[ЁёА-я].*?\]';
reg4 = reg4.replace(/\\/g, '\\\\');
//reg4 = reg4.replace(/(?<!\\)\\(?!\\)/g, '\\\\');
//reg4 = reg4.replaceAll("\\", "\\\\");
reg4 = new RegExp(reg4,'g');
let test4 = arr.filter(x => x.match(reg4));

console.log({
    test1 : test1,
    test2 : test2,
    test3 : test3,
    test4 : test4
});
```

The correct result is the first three elements of the array like in the `test1`, `test2`, `test3` results.

Any ideas on how to get a regex saved as a string : `reg4` to work to get the correct output?

Comment: `but I'd prefer not to save the regex in this form` Why not?

Comment: The reg4 doesn't work as you expect because when you escape a character that doesn't have special meaning, the result is just the character.

Comment: @TheMaster only because that would mean I'll have to edit a lot of regex already in a database table not just this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're already using a database, why not just change all the values :

```sql
UPDATE yourTable SET regexColumn = REPLACE (regexColumn, '\', '\\');
```

then you can use the `reg2` in your example.

or

you could match the first `\[` and the last `\]` and add an extra backslash to those which would make your `reg4` example work.

```js
let reg4 = '^\[.*?[ЁёА-я].*?\]';
reg4 = reg4.replace(/[[\]]/, '\\$&');

reg4 = new RegExp(reg4, 'g');
let test4 = arr.filter(x => x.match(reg4));
console.log(test4);
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sLrdxa7m/2/)

Comment: tnx, not the JavaScript answer I was looking for but certainly solves my problem, combined with @Dimava's answer for future regex inputs.

Comment: @idg7 updated my answer take a look.

Answer (score 2):

To save regex as a string use its `source`:

```
const r = /^\[.*?[ЁёА-я].*?\]/g
console.log('the regex source is %s, but as a string in JS code it has to be escaped as %o', o.source, o.source)
// the regex source is ^\[.*?[ЁёА-я].*?\], but as a string in JS code it has to be escaped as '^\\[.*?[ЁёА-я].*?\\]'

let source = r.source
let copy = new RegExp(source, 'g')
console.log(r.toString() === copy.toString()) // true

function copyAnyRegex(regex) {
  let source /* : string */ = regex.source
  let flags /* : string */ = regex.flags 
  return new RegExp(source, flags)
}
```

The regex escape slashes in string look like `/\w/` => `"\\w"` (`\w` string JSON) as they have to be escaped.
If you want to write those strings in JS code without escaping, write regexes directly and get their source: `/\w/.source`

Comment: tnx, useful for saving new regex, escaped and as string, but not for already existing regex saved, unescaped as string, which was my question.

Comment: @idg7 what is your current data format? (jsfidde website doesn't work for me ever)

Comment: jsfiddle just has a copy of the JavaScript code block that is in my question. As for the regex data that I have in my DB table, they are all similar to the `'^\[.*?[ЁёА-я].*?\]'` example above; which is regex saved as unescaped string .

Comment: If it's unescaped string as you show then I don't understand why `new Regex(/*'^\[.*?[ЁёА-я].*?\]'*/ db_string)` working

Comment: @idg7 can you please show me `console.log(JSON.stringify( regex_string: db_string ))`